# Django translation in 1.9

Tags: django, translation

I have a django project with one translation (call it 'en').

I have a simple menu for a user to select the language.

I used to do this:
If he selected the 'en' option, I would do:

```
request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = 'en'
```

and that would work.

If I wanted to disable the 'en' translation, I would do:

```
request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = ''
```

and that would restore the template original language.

Means if I have this in template:

```
{% trans "some non english text" %}
```

then setting the session cookie to '', would show the original text (no trans), which is what I wanted.
All of this true for django 1.7.

In django 1.9, this simply won't work, setting the session cookie language key to '', still keep the active translation.
How do I disable the translation correctly? I just want to show the website in its default language (output the template as is, no translation file).

**EDIT, SOLUTION:**
It worked differently in django < 1.8. Since 1.8 setting the session key to empty string does not mean "fallback to no translation". So what I did is to set the `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting to a code which I dont have a translation file for. That simply cause the template to appear as is.

Comment: Can't you just disable the translation in the `settings` of your project, like `USE_I18N = False`?

Comment: No, cause I still use the translation. I just want the option to switch between "no translation" and "translated". And at this moment I've just found a solution.

Comment: You should add your answer edit as an answer to your question rather than an addendum to the question